# Group the object value into common array by it's key value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below type of object, now I want to get the value of the object in a different array.
The array key is the value of the object key after underscore(_)

Actual Input:

```js
{"1_1":[1,2],"2_1":[2,1,3],"3_2":[4,5],"4_2":[6,7]}
```

Expected output:

```js
[
  1: [1, 2, 3],
  2: [4, 5, 6, 7]
]
```

Comment: does my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

iterate over your dict then create a new dict with key is the value of the object iterated key after underscore(_) using `split` funciton  then check if the expected object has already created an array with this key using `hasOwnProperty` you just append the value iterated element to the expected object .

Try this:

```js
   

 input = {
      "1_1": [1, 2],
      "2_1": [2, 1, 3],
      "3_2": [4, 5],
      "4_2": [6, 7]
    }
   expected={}
       for (e in input){
          if (!expected.hasOwnProperty(e.split('_')[1])){ 
            expected[e.split('_')[1]]=[]
          }
             input[e].forEach((r)=>{
              if (!expected[this.e.split('_')[1]].includes(r)){
                expected[this.e.split('_')[1]].push(r)
              }
            })
        }
    console.log(expected)
```

the `includes` method used to check if don't have a duplicated values in the expacted object  values

Comment: Could you please consider providing a clear explanation of how your code works?

Comment: is this helped you @Edric